# Another formula for $n$-th root of $n$ factorial, approximate or exact?

Tags: factorial

I was playing around with graphing formulas on Desmos, and I stumbled upon $\sqrt[n]{n!}$, which when graphed outputted a line that seemed to be perfectly linear, but wasn't. Is there *another* exact (or approximate) formula that could be used to fit the values outputted by $\sqrt[n]{n!}$, since it resembles very closely a linear equation? And if so, out of curiosity, is there one that doesn't use the factorial?

Comment: You might be interested in [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @Gary Yes you did, thank you (forgot to accept answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E1) asymptotic expansion of $\log n!$, we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{n}\log n! \sim \log n - 1 + \frac{{\log (2\pi n)}}{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{12n^2 }} - \frac{1}{{360n^4 }} +  \ldots\, .
$$
Taking the exponential of each side and expanding the exponential using its power series gives
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{{n!}} & \sim \frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\exp \left( {\frac{{\log (2\pi n)}}{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{12n^2 }} - \frac{1}{{360n^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
\\ &
 = \frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\left( {1 + \frac{{\log (2\pi n)}}{{2n}} + \frac{{3\log ^2 (2\pi n) + 2}}{{24n^2 }} + \frac{{\log ^3 (2\pi n) + 2\log (2\pi n)}}{{48n^3 }} +  \ldots } \right),
\end{align*}
as $n\to +\infty$. At leading order
$$
\sqrt[n]{{n!}} \sim \frac{n}{\mathrm{e}},
$$
confirming your observation.